# Handling several implementations of one Spring bean/interface

Tags: java, spring, interface

Say I need to rely on **several implementations** of a Spring bean. I have one `AccountService` interface and two implementations: `DefaultAccountServiceImpl` and `SpecializedAccountServiceImpl`.

1. How is this possible (injecting one or the other implementation) in Spring?
2. Which implementation will the following injection use?

   ```
   @Autowired
   private AccountService accountService;
   ```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ad. 1: you can use [`@Qualifier` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) or autowire using `@Resource` as opposed to `@Autowired` which defaults to field name rather than type.

Ad. 2: It will fail at runtime saying that two beans are implementing this interface. If one of your beans is additionally [annotated with `@Primary`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html), it will be preferred when autowiring by type.

Comment: Tomasz: I understand that I need to use `@Qualifier("specialized")` to specify the implementation that is going to be injected. Then if I define my service using java (instead of xml) how do I specify which qualifier it has? Will this do: `@Service("specialized")`?

Comment: @balteo: yes. Either assign service name manually in `@Service` annotation or take simple class name with first character lower cased: `@Qualifier("specializedAccountServiceImpl")`.

Answer (score 15):

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("impl1")
BaseInterface impl1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("impl2")
BaseInterface impl2;

@Component(value="impl1")
public class Implementation1  implements BaseInterface {

}

@Component(value = "impl2")
public class Implementation2 implements BaseInterface {

}


For full code: https://github.com/rsingla/springautowire/
```

Comment: What if I want to switch implementation for all the places where I @Autowire the interface? I don't want to specify explicitly at all usage places.

Comment: You can use Spring expression using @value and put the value in property file (application.properties) and switch back and forth bean the Qualifiers. (I havent tried this in this particular case but i am sure its just a string that the annotation is taking, so it should work fine.