# Create two same beans differ in dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a service class which depends on a Repository Bean

```
@Service
public class SomeService{
   private Repo repoClass;
   @Autowired
   public SomeService(Repo repoClass){
      this.repoClass = repoClass;
   }
   //Methods
}
```

However I have two kinds of Repo

```
public class JdbcRepo implements Repo{
}

public class HibernateRepo implements Repo {
}
```

How do I make two beans of `SomeService` which one is injected with `JdbcRepo` and another is injected with `HibernateRepo` ?

Comment: Please checkout the updated answer, let me know if you need further assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a simple solution here, please look into [`@Primary`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)

I am assuming that you are using the annotation driven approach:

```
@Primary
@Repository(value = "jdbcRepo")
public class JdbcRepo implements Repo{
}
```

> `@Primary` indicates that a bean should be given preference when
>   multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued
>   dependency. If exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates,
>   it will be the autowired value.

```
@Repository(value = "hibernateRepo")
public class HibernateRepo implements Repo {
}
```

To Inject the dependency, you can use `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier` or only `@Resource`.

> Now to inject `JdbcRepo`, you can just use `@Autowired`, because of
>   the `@Primary`:

```
@Service
public class SomeService{
   @Autowired
   private Repo repoClass;
}
```

> To inject `HibernateRepo`, you have to use the `@Qualifier`

```
 @Service
    public class RandomService{
       @Autowired
       @Qualifier("hibernateRepo")
       private Repo repoClass;
    }
```

---

> For your concern `two beans of SomeService which one is injected with JdbcRepo and another is injected with HibernateRepo`, You can follow
>   the same pattern for Service class that is followed for your
>   Repository.

```
public interface SomeService{
}

@Primary
@Service(value = "jdbcService")
public class  JdbcService extends SomeService{
   @Autowired
   private Repo repo;
}

@Service(value = "hibernateService")
public class  HibernateService extends SomeService{
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("hibernateRepo")
   private Repo repo;
}
```

To Inject `SomeService` with `jdbcRepo`:

```
@Autowired
private SomeService someService;
```

To Inject `SomeService` with `HibernateRepo`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("hibernateService")
private SomeService someService;
```

> Please take into these Stackoverflow threads for further reference:

- [Autowiring two beans implementing same interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534053/autowiring-two-beans-implementing-same-interface-how-to-set-default-bean-to-au)
- [Handling several implementations of one Spring bean/interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777079/handling-several-implementations-of-one-spring-bean-interface)

I hope this helps you, feel free to comment!

Comment: So In the end I have to have two class of `SomeService` ?

Comment: @IIISc That is just an example. Important here is the way `Repo` is injected, not the service class. It could be any spring managed bean, I mean wherever you want to inject. Anyways, I have rename the Service class to avoid confusion.

Let me know if you still hv doubts.

Comment: My main concern is to have two beans type, but each bean has different bean to be injected

Answer (score 1):

Define two `someService` bean in xml like this

```
<bean id="someservice" class="">
     <constructor-arg>
         <value>JdbcRepo</value>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="someservice2" class="">
     <constructor-arg>
         <value>HibernateRepo</value>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using annotation driven,simply use this

```
@Autowired private JdbcRepo jdbcRepo; 
@Autowired private HibernateRepo hibernateRepo ;
```