# Handling several implementations of one Spring bean/interface in one class field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777079/handling-several-implementations-of-one-spring-bean-interface), but I have this situation. Suppose I have one `AccountService` interface and two implementations: `DefaultAccountServiceImpl` and `SpecializedAccountServiceImpl`, (the classes just like in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777079/handling-several-implementations-of-one-spring-bean-interface)). The implementation is in one class, but has different bean implementation for different method. Say:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountManagerRestController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    HttpEntity<?> registerAccount(@RequestBody AccountRegisterRequestBody input) {
        // here the `service` is DefaultAccountServiceImpl
        ...
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/register/specialized", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    HttpEntity<?> registerSpecializedAccount(@RequestBody AccountRegisterRequestBody input) {
        // here the `service` is SpecializedAccountServiceImpl
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777079/handling-several-implementations-of-one-spring-bean-interface#answer-27339993) demonstrates autowiring two different implementations into one class. Just use the non-specialized implementation in your first method, and the specailized one in your second method.

Comment: What is the difference? You just have to create 2 different beans of AccountService and annotate them with `@Qualifier("DefaultAccountServiceImplBeanName")` and `@Qualifier("SpecializedAccountServiceImplBeanName")` respectively.

Comment: So, it CAN'T be assigned to ONE field?

Comment: @Morilla No you can't! How would Spring know which implementation you are trying to access?

Comment: @user2004685, maybe by annotating the method and pass the qualifier name on it. If such feature exists.

Comment: @Morilla Unfortunately these is no such feature and you'll have to go through the standard approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `@Qualifier("beanName")`

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("service1")
private AccountService service1;

@Autowired @Qualifier("service2")
private AccountService service2;
```

Comment: What if I have more than 2? Say 10. I have to declare 10 fields too?

Comment: @MorillaThaisa Then you have a rather serious design error and should find a sane way to handle it, such as a service registry.

Comment: Do you have some docs about "server registry"? How can I implement with Spring, I guess I have the same design problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the difference. You just have to create two different beans in this case and then annotate them with different `@Qualifier`.

Still if you do not get it, here is how you can achieve it:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountManagerRestController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("DefaultAccountServiceImpl")
    private AccountService serviceDAS;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("SpecializedAccountServiceImpl")
    private AccountService serviceSAS;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    HttpEntity<?> registerAccount(@RequestBody AccountRegisterRequestBody input) {
        /* Use ServiceDAS Here */
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register/specialized", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    HttpEntity<?> registerSpecializedAccount(@RequestBody AccountRegisterRequestBody input) {
        /* Use ServiceSAS Here */
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can replace the two annotations with one `@Resource` annotation like this:

```
@Resource(name = "DefaultAccountServiceImpl")
private AccountService serviceDAS;

@Resource(name = "SpecializedAccountServiceImpl")
private AccountService serviceSAS;
```

I prefer this approach as I do not have to use two annotations.

Comment: So, it CAN'T be assigned to ONE field? What if for several method, not just two, has different implementation?

Comment: If you are saying that you have more than 2 implementations for same interface then yes, you'll have to inject `n` number of beans of the same class for each and every implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For a few implementation, say 1 or two, using the @Qualifier notation is enough, but in the instance that the implementation will grow over time, a more scalable solution will be to utilize the factory pattern.

As such, only the factory class will be responsible for fetching the implementation depending on the implementation argument passed in. Thus, 
Service 1 implementation could be triggered by passing in "SERVICE1" as a string to the factory class which will return service 1in that manner.